# Shortcut to calculate a specific range in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

In VBA this can be easily done using the range.calculate command. 
Once somebody showed me how to do it in Excel with a keyboard shortcut but I do not remember it any more.
I have been searching the internet Unsuccessfully to find the shortcut.

Does anybody know the keyboard shortcut to calculate a pre-selected range in Excel?

George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify your version.  In Excel 2003 the closest you can come is to calculate your active sheet using shift+F9 (Just F9 will calculate the whole book).

You can create a macro though that activates `Range.Calculate` and give that macro a hotkey.  You can place that macro in your personal workbook so that it will work no matter what workbooks you have open.

Comment: I am using Excel 2003 and I believe that there is an Excel build-in keyboard shortcut to calculate a preselected range. 
My apologies if such functionality does not exist but I remember seeing it once in the past...

Comment: @George: [This](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-HP005203781.aspx) is a comprehensive list of all excel 2003 shortcuts.  There is no hotkey in excel 2003 to do what you want, but you can make a new hotkey to do this if you wish.

Comment: Thank you Dan, you are right, your original answer was the actual answer to the question.

Thank you very much for looking into this.

George